# Databricks SQL List delta column names between 2 tables

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, databricks-sql

I'm attempting to validate tables in databricks.
The tables were created by 2 different groups but is expected to be the same.
I just wanted to confirm this.
I just want to see if any columns are not present in both tables

Any suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how deep you want the comparison. If you just want to compare column lists then [get them](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.columns.html) and [compare](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python%20compare%20lists).

If you want deeper comparison then you can use [spark-extension
DIFF](https://github.com/G-Research/spark-extension/blob/master/DIFF.md).